# Не могу изменить строку. Где моя ошибка?

Tags: c#

Я разрабатываю свой мини-интерпретатор (не спрашивайте зачем), так вот у меня возникла проблема: "Препретатор"(как я его назвал) в самом начале обходит весь файл с кодом и ищет по ключевому слову "function" функции, а затем добавляет их в список в виде структуры (указывается номер строки её начала). Далее, в основном цикле, когда доходит очередь до строки вызова функции, "постпретатор" берёт структуру из списка и добавляет в неё номер строки инициализатора этой функции, затем оно перед символом завершения функции ("}") оно пишет команду вида "goto;8" и затем переводит номер строки выполнения на номер строку начала функции, затем после выполнения функции оно должно перевести номер строки выполнения обратно в основной цикл. Но функция может находится в любой части скрипта, поэтому и был придуман "препретатор". У меня же с одной функцией, всё работает, а вот с двумя уже не хочет: оно почему-то не подставляет команду перевода номера строки в первую функцию, а во вторую подставляет нормально.

```
Основной код C#
    /// <summary>
    /// Структура функции
    /// </summary>
    struct Function
    {
        public int start;
        public int point;
        public string name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список структур функции
    /// </summary>
    static SortedList<string, Function> funct = new SortedList<string, Function>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Препретатор функция
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="game">Массив строк всего скрипта</param>
    /// <param name="main">Сам скрипт</param>
    public static void Compilation(string[] game, ref string main)
    {
        //funct.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < game.Length; i++)
        {
            if (game[i].Split(';')[0] == "function")
            {

                //создание или "взятие" функции
                Function fn;
                if (!funct.ContainsKey(game[i].Split(';')[1]))
                {
                    fn = new Function();
                    fn.start = i + 1;
                    string name = game[i].Split(';')[1];
                    fn.name = name;
                    funct.Add(name, fn);
                }
                else
                {
                    fn = funct[game[i].Split(';')[1]];
                }

                //Подсчёт строк функции
                int o = 1;
                for (; !game[i + o].EndsWith("}"); o++) ;


                var rrrhhh = ""; //временная переменная с итоговым кодом скрипта
                var telo = "";//тело функции
                for (int p = 0; p < ((i + o)); p++)
                {
                    rrrhhh += game[p] + "\n";  //заполнение до конца функции                      
                }

                for (int q = i; q < i+o; q++)
                {
                    telo += game[q] + "\n"; //заполнение тела
                }
                telo = telo.Split('\n')[telo.Split('\n').Length - 2];//обрезка } (там 2 должно быть, потому что индекс с 0, а количество с 1)

                //Console.WriteLine(telo);

                if (!telo.Contains("goto;"))
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Insert(rrrhhh.Length, String.Format("goto;{0}", fn.point)+"\n}");//если "гото" нет, то добавляем
                else//иначе изменяем
                {
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Substring(0, rrrhhh.Length - 3);//обрезаем перенос строки и }
                    int y = rrrhhh.Length-1;//получаем длинну в виде индекса
                    int t = 0;//создает временную переменную
                    for (; rrrhhh[y] == ';'; y--, t++) ;//считаем от конца и до ; (это символ передачи аргументов)
                    //t++;
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Substring(0, rrrhhh.Length - t);//обрезаем по него
                    rrrhhh += ";" + fn.point.ToString() + "\n}";//добавляем новый "гото"
                    //Console.WriteLine(rrrhhh);
                }
                main = rrrhhh; //изменяем основной скрипт                                    
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Постпретатор функция
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="game">Массив строк со скриптом</param>
    /// <param name="main">Сам скрипт</param>
    /// <param name="name">Имя функции</param>
    public static void Compilation(string[] game, ref string main, string name)
    {
        ///Тут всё почти также как и там, но другой начало
        for (int i = 0; i < game.Length; i++)
        {
            if (game[i].Split(';')[0] == "function")
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i);
                Function fn = funct[name]; //получем функцию из списка по её имени

                //Далее всё вроде так же, хотя я мог что то изменить

                int o = 1;
                for (; !game[i + o].EndsWith("}"); o++) ;

                var rrrhhh = "";
                var telo = "";
                for (int p = 0; p < ((i + o)); p++)
                {
                    rrrhhh += game[p] + "\n";
                }

                for (int q = i; q < i + o; q++)
                {
                    telo += game[q] + "\n";
                }
                telo = telo.Split('\n')[telo.Split('\n').Length - 2];



                if (!telo.Contains("goto;"))
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Insert(rrrhhh.Length, String.Format("goto;{0}", fn.point) + "\n}");
                else
                {
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Substring(0, rrrhhh.Length - 3);
                    int y = rrrhhh.Length - 1;
                    int t = 0;
                    for (; rrrhhh[y] == ';'; y--, t++) ;
                    //t++;
                    rrrhhh = rrrhhh.Substring(0, rrrhhh.Length - t);
                    rrrhhh += ";" + fn.point.ToString() + "\n}";
                    //Console.WriteLine(rrrhhh);
                }

                main = rrrhhh;

                //Console.WriteLine(telo);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void loadgame(string path)
       {
       //Начало препретатора
        Console.WriteLine("Start Compilation");
        Compilation(game.Split('\n'), ref game);
        lenght = game.Split('\n').Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Stop Compilation");
        //конец препретатора

        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {

            switch (game.Split('\n')[i].Split(';')[0])
            {
                    case "func":
                    //func;test
                    Function fc = funct[game.Split('\n')[i].Split(';')[1]]; //получение из аргумента имени функции                      
                    fc.point = i+2; //передача текущего номера строки
                    funct[game.Split('\n')[i].Split(';')[1]] = fc; //замена функции в списке
                    Compilation(game.Split('\n'), ref game, game.Split('\n')[i].Split(';')[1]); //запуск постпретатора
                    //Compilation(game.Split('\n'), ref game);
                    lenght = game.Split('\n').Length;//пересчёт новой общей длинны скрипта
                    i = fc.start;//передача управления другой строке
                    break;
            }
        }
```

}

Это сам скрипт

```
func;test
//mess - просто текст в консоль выводит
mess;Добро пожаловать в Test.
func;fc
//функции
function;test
isfunction;
mess;Функция, функция
mess;Тело, тело
mess;Кто то батя в C#
}
isfunction;
function;fc
isfunction;
mess;Функция другая
}
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй отладчик. В методе Compilation 2 проблемы, одна фундаментальная.

1) Ты смотришь окончание строки, но не предусматриваешь возможный перевод строки, пробел, табуляцию

```
                //Подсчёт строк функции
                int o = 1;
                for (; !game[i + o].TrimEnd('\n', '\r').EndsWith("}"); o++) ;
```

2) В конце метода ты изменяешь основную переменную main, но расчёты ведешь на старых данных по переменной game. Тебе надо или отказаться от переменной game, или делать в неё инсерт строки goto.

```
                main = rrrhhh; //изменяем основной скрипт
```

[image: Массив в отладчике]

Comment: И плюс к этому нужна строка что бы к rrrhhh "долепить" все те строки, которые после неё. Спасибо большое за ответ, помогло.